# Replacing capital to small letter with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace I and A with lower case, using regex. (I already coded this using sent.lower(), which works fine. I want to know how to do the same by using regex)

```
import re
sent = 'hai Iam Ajay born in 1994'
re.sub(r'(\s)([A-Z])'$1\l$2',sent)
```

Comment: Try harder. Flagged for low effort.

Comment: Do you want to convert every uppercase character to lower case? If so then it seems like you could just call sent.lower()?

Comment: Actually i had done the same with .lower.I want to know how to do same by using regex.Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: Please fix the '' quotes in your `re.sub` call, currently that's not even legal syntax, and that call doesn't have three args, you've accidentally munged the `pattern` and `repl` args together. Please make sure your code as posted here is valid syntax; read through the [`re.sub()` doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20sub#re.sub) for examples, and try running them.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass in a function as the replacement. The function will return the corresponding replacement for a given match object.

I think `\b` (word boundary) here is more suitable than matching a space before the capital letter.

```
re.sub(r'\b[A-Z]', lambda x: x.group(0).lower(), sent)
```